Do I need to create two applications in order to use SSO?
I'm building a simple API using .NET Core 8.0 to receive a SQL Query or JSON and generate an Excel file with it.
Problem is that I'm new to OIDC/OAuth/Azure AD and my company needs to protect all APIs with SSO. In this case, since there will be no "web app" or "client app", is it possible to have the single sign-on? Or I'll have to also create a web page so users can click on login?

"my company needs to protect all APIs with SSO" - SSO doesn't "protect" anything - SSO is about delegation and federation. It's very easy to have an incredibly insecure website that integrates with SSO providers.

there will be no "web app" or "client app" Then what are you making? A desktop app? Then is the question is how to use SSO with a .NET Desktop app?

You are going to make an HTTP(s) connection between a client and a server.  SSO is not used.  SSO sends an unencrypted username and password.  When making an HTTP(s) connection credentials are used which encrypts the password so it cannot be hacked.  Your system may be using Windows Credentials or OAUTH2 credentials.

@jdweng "SSO sends an unencrypted username and password" - Sorry but what nonsense is this?

@Dai : SSO is a remote login and is like typing on a terminal.

@jdweng That is not what "SSO" means in the context of modern web/federated identity and delegated authentication: OIDC is an implementation of SSO. OAuth2 and SAML are also under the "SSO" umbrella - which most certainly do not involve any 1980s-style plaintext logins a-la unsecure shell access, so pray-tell, exactly which "SSO" are you referring to?

@Dai : I was getting it confuse with SLO.

@jdweng Shall we mutually agree to delete our comments in here? :D


Do I need to create two applications in order to use SSO?

Philosophically, if you were starting ex nihilio, then yes, because you'll need 1 web-application to serve as the IdP (aka OP), and another web-application to be an RP to the IdP, which makes sense: it takes two to tango.
But in your case: maybe, but not because you're using SSO.

You wrote this:

I'm building a simple API using .NET Core 8.0 to receive a SQL Query or JSON and generate an Excel file with it.

By "API" I think you really mean "web-service". Moving on...

Problem is that I'm new to OIDC/OAuth/Azure AD and my company needs to protect all APIs with SSO.

SSO systems do not "protect" anything: SSO is simply a means by which multiple, entirely separate, applications and services, can delegate the responsibility of user-identification (i.e. Identity and Authentication) to an IdP (or even multiple IdPs) - this means that each application does not need to maintain its own Users-database, Login/Forgot-Password page, and the rest. But it's up to each application to enforce their authorization rules (i.e. security and protection) based on the information received from the IdP.
Now watch this video.
So here's a sketch-quality table-of-analogies:



IdP
Example RP
Token
Example RP Client
Identity / User-Info






Country's passport agency
Another country's border crossing
Passport
You, handing over your passport
Passport




State/country's DMV
Booze shop
Driver's license
You, flashing your driving license photocard
Driver's license




On-prem Active Directory Federation Services
WCF SOAP Service
SAML XML
Windows desktop application
LDAP
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/saml-tokens-and-claims



On-prem Active Directory Federation Services
ASP.NET Core Web API
JWT / Reference-Token
Windows desktop application
LDAP
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-concepts



On-prem Active Directory + Kerberos
SQL Server
Kerberos
SQL Server Management Studio
LDAP




OAuth2 OP (non-OIDC)
Web-service
JWT / Reference-Token
Mobile device app
(not available)




OIDC OP (Azure Entra, IdentityServer, Auth0, etc)
Web-service
JWT / Reference-Token
Traditional (SSR) web-application (that uses normal Cookies, your JWT tokens will be embedded within the cookies)
id_token or UserInfoEndpoint




Sign-in-with-Google
Google Photos
JWT
Mobile device app
Google Identity Services





By analogy: the IdP is a state/country's DMV/DVLA that issues identity documents (photocard/biometric driver's licenses) that cannot be forged. An RP is a booze-shop that requires customers (users) to prove they're over 18/21 to buy that sweet, sweet Kentucky Bourbon: they do this by examining your driving license (because the shop recognizes and trusts the DMV; but they won't necessarily accept a driving license from another country (because they might not know how to verify it's authentic), let alone a hand-drawn ID-card on a paper napkin (because it doesn't prove anything)).
Note that SSOs take many forms: while the most well-known SSO schemes in the world today are Sign-in with Google and Azure Entra (fka Azure Active Directory), these are both web-centric and relatively recent inventions. In decades gone past other forms of SSO existed in on-prem (i.e. LAN) environments like Windows Server Domains + Active Directory, whereby instead of having users sign-in to a web-based login form to use SSO, they simply logged-into-Windows once and the NTLM/Kerberos system took-care of allowing those users to connect-to (i.e. authenticate) against other secured resources and services on their LAN, such as file-shares, database server, and web-applications.
...but today in 2024, if people mean Kerberos then they'll say Kerberos while the term "SSO" has entirely web-based connotations now.


In this case, since there will be no "web app" or "client app", is it possible to have the single sign-on? Or I'll have to also create a web page so users can click on login?

This SQL/JSON/Excel web-service of yours sounds like it's only intended to be used by other software programs, so I assume its interface to the world is going to be either RESTful-ish, SOAP, XML+RPC, or is otherwise built on HTTP (and by "HTTP" I really mean HTTPS or QUIC, of course).
...which means that other software that connects-to and uses your service (i.e. your service's clients) will be other applications or services which are directly user-facing, right? If so, then that means your organization already has an IdP set-up and running - and all your web-service needs to do is register itself as an RP (aka "application", even if it's a service) with the IdP and decide what forms of authX your service will accept, then add some authX middleware, and that's pretty much it.
In concrete terms, this means you'd likely be using Azure Entra ("cloud-y") or Active Directory Federation Services (on-prem/LAN/extranet), which means you'll be using OIDC or SAML, which means the incoming HTTP requests to your web-service will have a Bearer Token (often a JWT, but not always) stored in the HTTP Request Headers. Your service's authX middleware will examine this bearer-token and verify it's actually from the IdP (using only local cryptography; no (expensive/slow) network calls are necessary at all) and that's it.
If your web-service needs to communicate with other web-services (that all use the same IdPs) then you can either use a delegation token (which requires extra set-up by your sysadmins) or just appropriate (i.e. forward) the bearer-token as-is, provided that token is authorized to use those other web-services and it's permitted by your SSO scheme (e.g. OIDC aud (audience) checks).


Or I'll have to also create a web page so users can click on login?

You won't need to make any web-pages for users to interact with, provided that you're only making a web-service that's consumed by other applications/services.
If you're making a web application (with HTML and cookies and all the things) then that's another question entirely - and is more complicated.

